# Javascript - How to onclick play several files various formats e.g. video and audio in one function

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I tried to create a function to play and pause a video. But wondering if i could include also a audio file. Thanks.

```
var audio = document.getElementById("myAudio");
        var video = document.getElementbyId("myVideo"); 

        function playFile() { 
        audio.play();
        video.play();

        } 

        function pauseFile() { 
        audio.pause();
        video.pause(); 
        }
```

Comment: what is myAudio then? not an audio?

Comment: it is an an html <audio> tag with the id of myAudio also for video the same thing.
`<audio id="myAudio" src="assets/music.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
   </audio>
  <div>
   <button onclick="playFile()" type="button">Play Audio</button>
   <button onclick="pauseFile()" type="button">Pause Audio</button>
  </div>`

Comment: So my next question : playfile() does it not play both video and audio as the function tells it to?